# Swift 3 how do you change colors dynamically

Tags: mysql, swift

I have a column in a MySQL database for each user called "theme". I would like to know how to change colors based on that variable. Here is the code I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
// First function
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let theme = (user!["theme"] as! String?) ?? "" // dark

    if theme == "dark" {
        let color1 = UIColor(red: 93/255, green: 75/255, blue: 81/255, alpha: 1)
        let color2 = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 251/255, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1)


    // Set colors
    fullName.textColor = color2
```

}

Comment: Note it works fine if I just define color2 outside of my if statement: let color2 = UIColor(red: 93/255, green: 75/255, blue: 81/255, alpha: 1)

Comment: What value does "theme" have, when you get it from your dicitonary? Do you have some background, what is within the dicitonary stored ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the color variables inside the if statement so their scope limits to that if statement only you cannot access it outside the braces of if-Statement.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let theme = (user!["theme"] as! String?) ?? "" // dark
  let color1 : UIColor?
  let color2 : UIColor?

      if theme == "dark" {
           color1 = UIColor(red: 93/255, green: 75/255, blue: 81/255, alpha: 1)
           color2 = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 251/255, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1)
      }

// Set colors
fullName.textColor = color2
```

you can use this as above by defining vaiables outside the if statement.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are making color2 locally in the scope of if statement

Update ur method like that

```
class YourClassName{  var color2: UIColor? 
    func viewDidLoad()
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let theme = (user!["theme"] as! String?) ?? "" // dark
    if theme == "dark" {
        let color1 = UIColor(red: 93/255, green: 75/255, blue: 81/255, alpha: 1)
        color2 = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 251/255, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    // Set colors
    fullName.textColor = color2
    }}
```